# How can get a column where my result is 1 2 3 6 7 8 I want to exclude the common IDs from both the table and display the result in one column

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have Two tables T1 and T2 with ID as the column. For example

T1:ID

```
1              
2              
3              
4              
5
```

T2:ID

```
4
5
6
7
8
```

How can get a column where my result is 1 2 3 6 7 8 I want to exclude the common IDs from both the table and display the result in one column.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: I noticed your question is getting downvoted. If you do not understand why it is getting downvoted, then consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). I suspect that if you had posted the text of a SQL statement and shown its undesirable result, then you probably would not have been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . one method is `union all`:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
union all
select t1.id
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use minus

```
select id from 
(
select id from t1 
union 
select id from t2
) a
minus select id from (
select  id from t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS support `FULL OUTER JOIN` then i would do :

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t2.id = t1.id
where (t1.id is null or t2.id is null);
```